# Why are abstract data types only implemented by concrete data types?

Tags: object, data-structures, language-agnostic, terminology, abstract-data-type

In Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java (3rd edition) by Mark Allen Weiss when he talks about section 3.1 Abstract Data Types, page 57, why does he only implement or say that abstract data types must/should be implemented by concrete data types? I thought you can implement an abstract data type with another abstract data type, why do it specifically with a concrete data type?

Comment: Can you quote the section where this is mentioned so it would be easier for us to help you ?

Comment: If it's not concrete, then it's not an implementation.